# how to integrate our server with swagger to test dummy data?

Tags: api, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I have a question regarding Swagger.

You can find 'try it out!' button at below URL. It's a way of Swagger to integrate with API server.

Here in this example, I guess Swagger has used a Sandbox.

http://petstore.swagger.io/

[image: try it out button]

I would like to know how this integration with server(sandbox) is done with Swagger ?

Because I want to send dummy data as API result until my API is up and running.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-mock-api), which takes a Swagger file and generates a dummy API that you can call for your tests.

It's really easy to setup on Nodejs, and can help you build Front-end/Services by calling it.

You can design first your API layer using for instance the [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/), without actually writting code.

Comment: I will look into it and will post if i dont get anything. thank you very much bsoulier.